# How to stop ongoing uploading file method when user clicks delete button using react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to stop uploading a file on pressing delete button. The code works but this logs some output to console about some put operations .

Below is the code,

```
handle_upload = () => { 
    this.upload(item.id);
}

upload = () => {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: upload_definition.upload.region,
        accessKeyId: upload_definition.upload.credentials.access_key_id,
        secretAccessKey: upload_definition.upload.credentials.secret_access_key,
        sessionToken: upload_definition.upload.credentials.session_token,
    });

    const upload = new S3.ManagedUpload({
        params: {
            Bucket: upload_definition.upload.bucket_name,
            Key: upload_definition.upload.prefix + file.name,
            Body: file,
        },
    });

    this.upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {
        const new_percent = progress.loaded / progress.total * 100;
        const new_percent_rounded_five = Math.round(new_percent / 5) * 5;
        if (new_percent_rounded_five > self.state.percent && 
        new_percent_rounded_five <= 100) {
            self.setState({percent: new_percent_rounded_five});
        }
    });

    try {
        await upload.promise();
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({upload_failed: true});
        return;
    }

 }
```

The above code works fine. While uploading file in progress i can click cancel button to cancel uploading file. In doing so , it leaves log in the console that the access to s3 is blocked and other errors. how can i fix them or abort this loading when the cancel button is clicked using promise in react.

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html), I found that you actually have an `abort` method which could be called whenever the cancel button is pressed:

```
handle_upload = () => { 
    this.upload(item.id);
}

upload = () => {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: upload_definition.upload.region,
        accessKeyId: upload_definition.upload.credentials.access_key_id,
        secretAccessKey: upload_definition.upload.credentials.secret_access_key,
        sessionToken: upload_definition.upload.credentials.session_token,
    });

    this.uploadManager = new S3.ManagedUpload({
        params: {
            Bucket: upload_definition.upload.bucket_name,
            Key: upload_definition.upload.prefix + file.name,
            Body: file,
        },
    });

    try {
        await this.uploadManager.promise();
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({upload_failed: true});
        return;
    }

 }

 onCancel = () => {
     this.uploadManager.abort();
 }
```

Comment: thanks but not working in my case. within the documentation i see this note "Calling abort() in the browser environment will not abort any requests that are already in flight."